# React-native redux state change doesn't update (in view?) [beginner]

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, immutable.js

I'm getting recently into react/react-native.
I build a simple counter-app to get used to the libraries (using hooks, redux, immutable.js) and now I'm desperately stuck since the "counter value" doesn't get updated (or maybe just the view doesn't get re-rendered?)

**At top level:**

```
const store = createStore(reduce)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

**My reducer:** (i have a unit test for state updates that passes, therefore i think this part is actually not problematic? :) )

```
const initialState = fromJS({ counter: 0 })

export default function reduce (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state.update('counter', counter => counter + 1)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function selectCounter (state) {
  return state.get('counter')
}
```

**My screen looks as follows**

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const count = useSelector(selectCounter)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Counter: {count}</Text>
      <Button title='test' onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })} />
    </View>
  )
}
export default HomeScreen
```

I would be deeply grateful if anyone could enlighten me what I'm doing wrong here!

**EDIT** I figured it out: I used `#onClick` instead of `#onPress` inside my Button ...